# Can't see JDBC driver queries on BigQuery in Stackdriver Logging

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a BigQuery Sink set up to audit queries done on our BigQuery project that is a simple exclusion filter: `resource.type="bigquery_resource"`. This drops logs that match this filter into a BigQuery dataset.

We have been unable to see (and therefore audit) any queries that are executed via [Mode](https://app.mode.com/) which is connected by the [Starburst BigQuery JDBC driver](https://docs.starburstdata.com/302-e/connector/bigquery.html). How come we can't see these in our logs?

If I search in Stackdriver Logging directly for the query I ran on Mode, I can't see it. If I go to the BigQuery UI and go to `Query History` > `Project History` I can't see it. Is it not supported at this time? How would we track BigQuery costs on queries executed in this fashion?

Comment: I'm just wildly guessing but maybe the service account keys used by Mode are running from another project_id or maybe you need more permissions to see other users queries.

Comment: Not a bad assumption. We have a service account key that we assigned to the connector and I am an owner of the project. The only logs we can see from this service account key is when Mode has failed to create a table in the BigQuery project; this is when Mode tries to read a view because Mode seems to duplicate the table underneath the view since it doesn't support them in BigQuery without doing that. Pretty strange! Thanks for your input

Comment: I wonder if using this same service key to run a query directly from a client (Python for instance) the queries would appear in the query history. If it doesn't then maybe it's something related to the key.